# WPF Can't find local resource when executed

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm defining an application resource in my app that stores my ViewModels with a navigation element to navigate pages. This is working fine in the xaml editor of visual studio since all the data bindings are working there. However when I try to run the application in debugger it trows an Exception with the message `Cannot find source with the name ViewModelLocator.` Does anyone know what is going wrong?

I have a local resource defined in my App.xaml like this:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <viewmodel:ViewModelLocator x:Key="ViewModelLocator"/>
</Application.Resources>
```

Which i try to use like this:

```
<Page x:Class="QardPrint.PageEmployeesList"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:QardPrint"
  xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:QardPrint.ViewModel"
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
  Title="PageEmployeesList"
  DataContext="{Binding EmployeesListViewModel, Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}}">
```

My ViewModelLocator class looks like this

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    public EmployeesListViewModel EmployeesListViewModel => new EmployeesListViewModel(App.Navigation);
}
```

Comment: Are the `ViewModelLocator` and the `App.xaml` in the same assembly?

Comment: Yes they both are in the same assembly. They are in a different namespace, but I also tried to put them in the same namespace and the Exception still popped up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found the problem. It was in the App.xaml I deleted the startup parameter. After adding it again the problem was solved. 
I did this because I made another window in the startup function of app.cs. But this is probably bad design anyway so going to figure out how to do it better.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `ResourceDictionary`:

**App.xaml:**

```
<Application xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:QardPrint.ViewModel">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <viewmodel:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" />
```

**QardPrint.PageEmployeesLis.Xaml:**

```
<Page x:Class="QardPrint.PageEmployeesList"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:QardPrint"
  xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:QardPrint.ViewModel"
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
  Title="PageEmployeesList"
  DataContext="{Binding EmployeesListViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately i get the same error.

Comment: Have you tried to clean the solution and rebuild it?

Comment: Cleaning and rebuilding didn't help. I transferred minimal code to a new project and that seemed to work. Gonna move more code over stop by step to see where the problem occurs.